# Where to store SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI?

Tags: google-app-engine, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-platform, flask-sqlalchemy, app.yaml

I am following a code sample at
[How to connect to Cloud SQL from GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql)
and there is another tutorial at  [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) both talk about setting up the following variables,

```js
 SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

The first [1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-sql) tutorial stores it in app.yaml and the second one [2](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database) in config.py
What is the difference between these two files and where exactly should I store them?
Is there a best practice to follow?

Comment: Edit your question and indicate what research you have done into the problem before you came here. Show what you have looked for (basically, what you have googled), and what you found (if nothing then say so). In other words, show your work. Show the busy people who want to help you that you have done all you can to help yourself first.

Comment: According to the [Google Cloud docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#Node.js_app_yaml_Defining_environment_variables), you _can_ (it's not a must) define your env vars in `app.yaml`. `app.yaml` is [_a configuration file that contains cpu, memory, network and disk resources, scaling configuration, and general settings_](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml). [More to follow](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuration-files) on App Engine config files.